# Adding different meta-tags from database for each show page in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have events records in database, each one having a "meta_keywords" field.

When I show one event, I want to generate a meta tag in the page so that the event show page can be referenced by search engines.

Expected:

```
<meta name="description" content="My great event">
<meta name="keywords" content="Event topics">
```

How can I do this in rails 5?

Answer (score 1):

Found answer here with detailed steps:
https://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-page-titles/

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def meta_tag(tag, text)
    content_for :"meta_#{tag}", text
  end

  def yield_meta_tag(tag, default_text='')
    content_for?(:"meta_#{tag}") ? content_for(:"meta_#{tag}") : default_text
  end
end
```

In the head section of layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<meta name='description'
  content='<%= yield_meta_tag(:description, 'Default description') %>' />
<meta name='keywords'
  content='<%= yield_meta_tag(:keywords, 'defaults,ruby,rails') %>' />
```

In posts#show:

```
<% meta_tag :description, @post.description %>
<% meta_tag :keywords, @post.keywords.join(',') %>
```